# WPF - Marking an image with pushpins

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, maps

[image]

- I need to show an image (fixed-size) in a WPF application.
- It should be able to mark the image with pins as shown in above
  image.
- It should be able to add description for each pins and, when hovering
  on the pin the description should be shown.
- Finally I need to save all the information in SQL database to display
  the pins again.

Is that possible to achieve this by creating a custom control?
Please suggest me your ideas for implementing this solution. 
Providing examples will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:  Yes it's possible.

I would highly recommend the [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) architectural pattern when working with WPF.  What you need is:

1. A [canvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx) control in order to use absolute positioning
2. An [image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image(v=vs.110).aspx) control that will display the background image
3. A custom pin control that will display the image of the pins.  This control could also contain a DataTemplate that will be used to generate the description control.
4. A custom control that will display information about the pin (Will be used in the popup)
5. An [adorner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743737(v=vs.100).aspx) that will render the pin info popup in an adorner layer.  Place the adorner decorator in the same position as the canvas.

The information that you need to store about a pin:

1. Its Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left values
2. Properties that affect its visual characteristics (e.g. image, color etc)
3. The information displayed in its popup (e.g. description, image)

You can then read all the entries from the database and create a pin view model for each entry and bind the view models to an items control in the canvas.  Don't forget to bind properties of the pin control to the respective values of its view model (e.g. Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top, Description etc).

As for the popup, once you created your adorner class, add an instance of it to the adorner layer of your canvas when you need to show the popup and remove it when you need to close the popup.

An example of the style of the map control can be seen below (Assumes view model of map control contains an observable collection of pins):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Map}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Map}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <Grid>
                        <AdornerDecorator></AdornerDecorator>

                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <Canvas Background="White">

                                    </Canvas>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <local:Pin></local:Pin>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
                                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
                                </Style>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here's an example of an adorner control that simply renders a given FrameworkElement:

```
public class ControlAdorner : Adorner {

    FrameworkElement _control;
    public FrameworkElement Control {
        get {
            return (_control);
        }
        set {
            _control = value;
        }
    }

    public ControlAdorner(UIElement Element, FrameworkElement Control)
        : base(Element) {
        this.Control = Control;
        this.AddVisualChild(this.Control);
        this.IsHitTestVisible = false;
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) {
        if (index != 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        return _control;
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount {
        get {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public void UpdatePosition(Point point) {
        VisualOffset = new Vector(point.X, point.Y);
        this.InvalidateVisual();
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint) {
        Control.Measure(constraint);
        return Control.DesiredSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize) {
        Control.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(VisualOffset.X, VisualOffset.Y - 20), finalSize));
        return new Size(Control.ActualWidth, Control.ActualHeight);
    }
}
```

And here's how to make the Pin control display the adorner when the mouse is hovering:

```
public class Pin : Control {
    public DataTemplate DescriptionItemTemplate {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(DescriptionItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DescriptionItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionItemTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DescriptionItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(Pin), new PropertyMetadata(null));




    ControlAdorner _adorner;
    AdornerLayer _adornerLayer;

    static Pin() {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Pin), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Pin)));
    }

    public Pin() {
        this.MouseEnter += Pin_MouseEnter;
        this.MouseLeave += Pin_MouseLeave;
    }

    private void Pin_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        _adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this);

        FrameworkElement element = DescriptionItemTemplate.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;
        if (element == null) { return; }
        element.DataContext = this.DataContext;

        _adorner = new ControlAdorner(this, element);
        _adornerLayer.Add(_adorner);
    }


    private void Pin_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        _adornerLayer.Remove(_adorner);
        _adorner = null;
    }
}
```